# How To Append Data To A Column Without Inserting Another Row In Flask SQL alchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Really need your help as i'm banging my head against a wall here.

I have this flask app and i can add new crypto buys fine.

[crypto buys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haqrw.png)

However i want to add additional purchases to the same row without inserting a new one with the same existing crypto name in that row and just add another buy purchase. I effectively don't want more rows with BTC in and just the one, but with a list of purchases over time.

So in above screenshot for BTC row for example. If i want to add another purchase to existing 'crypto price' and 'amount paid' row id 15.

At the moment if i click 'add new purchase' and enter the price and amount paid i get this error.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPetK.png)

This is my code for app.py and update.html:

```
# install these packages PyMySql, mysql, mysqlclient?, cryptography

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.sql import  text



app = Flask(__name__)

db = SQLAlchemy(app) # assign DB to flaskapp

app.config.from_pyfile(
   'config.py' ) # use seperate file in this dir for config not built in variables. extra slash escape

class crypto_buys_tb(db.Model): # database table for crypto buys
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    crypto_name = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)    # these are the db columns and datatypes for columns
    crypto_price = db.Column(db.DECIMAL(20, 3)) # Use 'Decimal' to allow numbers with dec points. '20' is how many digits column can store before dec point.
    # '3' is how many digits after dec plac
    amount_paid = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, crypto_name, crypto_price, amount_paid):  # when a class instance is created, params needed
        self.crypto_name = crypto_name
        self.crypto_price = crypto_price
        self.amount_paid = amount_paid

db.create_all() # remove to create columns in the db at the beginning




# lines with @app.route are the end urls to various pages

@app.route('/')
def index():

        return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/insert', methods=['POST'])
def insert():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        crypto_name = request.form['crypto_name']
        crypto_price = request.form['crypto_price']
        amount_paid = request.form['amount_paid']

        entered_data = crypto_buys_tb(crypto_name, crypto_price, amount_paid)


        db.session.add(entered_data)
        db.session.commit()

        flash("Crypto Entered Successfully")  # flash message using flash library in flask

        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    else:

        return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/latest', methods=['GET']) # code for the latest page
def  latest():
        all_records = crypto_buys_tb.query.all()
        return render_template('latest_purchases.html', all_records = all_records)

@app.route('/delete/<id>/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def delete(id):
    crypto_id = crypto_buys_tb.query.get(id)
    db.session.delete(crypto_id)
    db.session.commit()
    flash("Crypto Deleted Successfully")

    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/update/<id>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def update(id):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        get_id = crypto_buys_tb.query.get(id)
        #c_name = get_id.crypto_name
        added_crypto = request.form['crypto_price']
        added_amount_paid = request.form['amount_paid']

        sql = db.session.execute(text(f"INSERT INTO crypto_buys_tb where id=get_id (crypto_price, amount_paid) VALUES (:{added_crypto}, :year, :{added_amount_paid})"))

        #db.session.execute(sql)
        db.session.commit()
    return render_template('update.html', id=id)






if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
<! -- this is the update function on app.py -->

{% extends 'jinja temp.html' %}

{% block body %}

{% include 'Header.html' %}

<br>
<br>
<br>

<!-- Form and grid layout-->
    <form action="{{url_for('update', id=id)}}" method="POST" class="form-row justify-content-md-center">

    <div  class="shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">

<h2 class="font-italic" style="text-align: center"><b> Update And Add Another Purchase</b> </h2> <!-- form header -->
        <br>
            <div class="col-md-auto mb-3"> <!-- width of the form boxes-->




                <br>

                <div class="form-group">

                <label><b>Current Price Of Crypto $</b></label>
    <input type="number" step="any" class="form-control" name="crypto_price" required >

                </div>

                <br>

                <div class="form-group">

                <label><b>Amount Paid £</b></label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="amount_paid" required>

                </div>


                <br>


                <div class="form-group">



                <button  class="btn btn-outline-primary float-right btn-md"
                 type="submit">Add Crypto Purchase</button></a>





                </div>

                <br>

            </div>
            </div>

        </form>



{% endblock %}
```

I really could do with some help, and very appreciative of your time.

Thanks

Comment: You don't want to store multiple transactions in the same row of a table. You want to use a child table to store each transaction in a separate row. Do some research on what a "normalized" database structure looks like. Then, if you want to *display* multiple transactions on a single row you can address that issue while still having a database structure that makes sense.

Comment: Ok thanks. So i cannot add additonal values for buys into the same row then in the same table?. It has to be a child table that points to it? is that what you're saying?. Thanks

Comment: A separate child table for the repeating items is by far the most common approach. There are ways to store multiple values in a single column (e.g., some databases support columns that contain JSON data), but they are usually reserved for specific cases that warrant it. This does not seem to be such a case.

Comment: thank you for getting back to me. So in my instance would it be a wise idea to not have the purchases in that same table with the crypto and to have a seperate table just for purchases only that would allow mutliple under each column for price paid and amount purchased?. I gather i would need to link this back to the main table under the crypto listed?. Thanks again for all your help

Answer (score 0):

The error you've posted show that the query that you are trying to execute is wrong. It expects parameters, but you haven't given it any.

> ```py
> sql = db.session.execute(text(f"INSERT INTO crypto_buys_tb where id=get_id (crypto_price, amount_paid) VALUES (:{added_crypto}, :year, :{added_amount_paid})"))
> ```

[This tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql) shows how to format properly a sql query for SQLAlchemy.

In your case, that could look like

```py
query = text("INSERT INTO crypto_buys_tb where id=get_id (crypto_price, amount_paid) VALUES (:added_crypto, :year, :added_amount_paid)")
db.session.execute(query, {"added_crypto": added_crypto, "added_amount_paid", "year": year}
```

assuming that the variable `year` is defined earlier.

Comment: hi. Apologies in the delay i'm working away but will be back tomorrow and give this a try and let you know. Thanks for replying Florent. really appreciate it!

Comment: i tried that and got this error                                           
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where id=get_id (crypto_price, amount_paid) VALUES ('10', '10')' at line 1")
[SQL: INSERT INTO crypto_buys_tb where id=get_id (crypto_price, amount_paid) VALUES (%(added_crypto)s, %(added_amount_paid)s)]
[parameters: {'added_crypto': '10', 'added_amount_paid': '10'}]